# Quota for the creation of comment exceeded, 24 hour quota for this user is 6

Tags: bug, android-app

I attempted to comment on a question in Android Enthusiasts, and got the error message shown in the title. Using the latest version of the android app.

Comment: no mention of such a quota in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide

Comment: @kate I would post a picture, but the android app doesn't support it.

Comment: @KateGregory the API has different limits than browsing the site, this would be an API limit.

Comment: So you can only make 6 comments per day? That's... terrible

Comment: @JeffryLin what do you mean the app "doesn't support it"? The app can't "disallow" screenshots... It's a matter of the device. Do you mean the _device_ doesn't support screenshots?

Comment: @Doorknob and to make it even worse, we have to wait 15 _seconds_ between each one! Even worse still, if you attempt to comment _during_ those 15 seconds, the timer is _reset_! That's right! Reset! _Re. Set!_ The agony!

Comment: @ColeJohnson The timer for comments always resets, even on the main sites. That's not anything new.

Comment: @cole you can't upload images with the app

Comment: I somewhat believe this limit was applied when the app was still in alpha version to prevent abuse. Nowadays, I believe user can comment more than 6 times from the mobile app.